# Live Camera Problems in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, sdk, camera, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

Question regarding an iPhone application we have developed which uses the live camera function.

Details:

1. We are layering an adjustable semi-transparent image over the live camera feed
2. When the user adjusts the semi-transparent image to a location that happens to cover (in any part) the camera button, it renders the camera button unclickable and the user is left frustrated - unable to snap the photo.

Question:

1. Does anyone have a suggestion for how we might be able to overcome the default features of the camera function (ie: default is the camera bar and camera button are the bottom-most layer - and we haven't found a way to change it to a different, higher layer to allow for our semi-transparent image to be on the bottom to avoid the clicking problem)?
2. Can anyone think of a workaround that might work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If OS 3.1 is an option for end-user phones, take a look at the new 3.1 camera APIs. In summary, set the showsCameraControls property to NO, set the cameraOverlayview property to your own view, and use the takePicture method to hook up to your own control for taking the picture.  You'll also need to implement imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo to save the image after the picture is taken.

The goal, of course, is to eliminate the stock controls and use your own that you can control for placement.

[UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

has further information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You might also check out [ARKit](http://www.iphonear.org/).  I haven't used it yet or had time to play with it.  From looking at it, it seems like apple would not sanction it, but it seems to pick apart the UIImagePicker control to remove all the chrome around the view finder.

Comment: I tried this. It's quite a nice little app and with the new overlay support mentioned below, it could indeed be sanctioned by Apple